# Replace character in string column in SQL query

Tags: sql, azure

I am trying to return every column from an SQL table and replace any '/' in a certain string column with '_' in the query itself as follows:

```
SELECT *,
       REPLACE(stringCol, '/', '_') AS stringCol
INTO [output]
FROM [input]
TIMESTAMP BY dateTimeColumn
```

The problem is, the original stringCol isn't overwritten, and the only way to see the results is to make a new column.

TO CLARIFY:
By overwrite, I am referring to the column returned by the query. I want to select every column from the source data, change the string column, then return that though the query but leave the source data unchanged.

Anyone got any ideas how to force the original column to be overwritten with the replaced variant?

Thanks!:)

->This is an azure streaming job<-

I can't change the source data at all, I need to replace the characters so that the results of the query are updated for the next place the data is sent to.

Comment: Do UPDATE instead of SELECT.

Comment: You state you need to replace and overwrite and also you can't change the source data - your comments are contradictory please clarify exactly what you expect your query to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update the table itself you could use:

```
UPDATE INPUT
SET stringCol = REPLACE(stringCol, '/', '_')
```

If you are just trying to replace the column in your query result only I would suggest listing out the columns resulting from the select * statement and replacing stringCol with
`REPLACE(stringCol, '/', '_') as stringCol`

Edit:
`REPLACE(stringCol,'//','_') as stringCol` should work

Comment: I am trying to do the latter, the problem is that the original string column is returned, not the replaced one when I use ```REPLACE(stringCol, '/', '_') as stringCol```

Comment: Try
 ```REPLACE(stringCol,'//','_') as stringCol``` I'm wondering if the backslash needed to be escaped. Let me know if it worked and I'll edit my original answer!

Comment: Hi there, if this answered your issue please mark as the correct answer